# Codeception with virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, codeception

Is anyone using codeception with a virtual host? If so, how did you get it to work?

I have two test machines, one WAMP, one Ubuntu, both with virtual hosts set up. When I run a very basic codeception acceptance test, I get a response that looks like it's trying to go to the default page, rather than my virtual host's index page.

My virtual host is called test; part of my `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1       test
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test

    DocumentRoot '/home/joel/projects/web/test'
    <Directory '/home/joel/projects/web/test'>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm pretty much just using the default acceptance suite setup file; the only change was to enter the name of my virtual machine in `tests/acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://test'
```

In `/home/joel/projects/web/test/index.html`, I have a very simple web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello, World!
</body>
</html>
```

I can successfully load this page in any browser that I try, including wget and curl.

My codeception test is also very simple. At `tests/acceptance/WelcomeCept.php`:

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Hello');
```

When I try to run this test, I get this output:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v1.6.6
Powered by PHPUnit 3.7.24 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Suite unit started

Suite functional started

Suite acceptance started
Running WelcomeCept.php - Failed


Time: 15 ms, Memory: 20.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) WelcomeCept.php
Ups, I couldn't see "Hello",
Failed asserting that 
--> It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
--> contains "hello".

Scenario Steps:
2. I see "Hello"
1. I am on page "/"

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

My default web page (127.0.0.1) does return the "It works!" message, but anything to the virtual host goes to the "Hello, World" page. Any idea why codeception is not going to my virtual host? Any ideas on how to track down what's causing the issue?

Thank you!

--Joel

---

**Edit:**

I figured it out. The port number was needed in in `tests/acceptance.suite.yml`, so this does not work:

```
config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://test'
```

But this does work:

```
config:
    PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://test:80'
```

That doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and it's not intuitive, so I put in a pull request to default to port 80. This may be a non-issue shortly.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. That's saved me some time with the same issue!